# .htaccess broke my website

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu Server 16.0.4 with apache 2.4.25 and PHP 5.6

bellow my **.htaccess** line code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I wondering why my website blank when i create file.htaccess, any wrong with my .htaccess ?

bellow my apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
         </Directory>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
<VirtualHost/>
```

Comment: What's your error log show? Whats `RewriteCond $1` doing?

Comment: nothing error in log file, like a magic.

Comment: What is the `RewriteCond $1` supposed to be doing? That looks like a capture group syntax, the first part of the rewritecond should be what you are matching.